# Copying Swift arrays from background to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, marshalling

If we go from Swift background to foreground, what is the proper way to [nsObject copy] in Swift?

For example in Objective-C, we would loop through a long array of ALAssets (say like 10,000+) in the background by doing:

```
[alGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *alPhoto, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
  {
    // Here to make changes for speed up image loading from device library...

    // =====================================================
    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IN BACKGROUND <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    // =====================================================

    if(alPhoto == nil)
    {
      c(@"number of assets to display: %d", (int)bgAssetMedia.count);
      // c(@"All device library photos uploaded into memory...%@", bgAssetMedia);
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
      {
       // =====================================================
       // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IN FOREGROUND <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       // =====================================================
        [ui hideSpinner];

       if (_bReverse)
         // Here we copying all the photos from device library into array (_assetPhotos)...
         _assetPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[bgAssetMedia copy] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
       else
         _assetPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[bgAssetMedia copy]];

        // NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)_assetPhotos.count);
         if (_assetPhotos.count > 0)
         {
           result(_assetPhotos);
         }
      });
    } else {
      // if we have a Custom album, lets remove all shared videos from the Camera Roll
      if (![self isPhotoInCustomAlbum:alPhoto])
      {
        // for some reason, shared glancy videos still show with 00:00 minutes and seconds, so remove them now
        BOOL isVideo = [[alPhoto valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqual:ALAssetTypeVideo];
        int duration = 0;
        int minutes  = 0;
        int seconds  = 0;
        // NSString *bgVideoLabel = nil;
        if (isVideo)
        {
          NSString *strduration = [alPhoto valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration];

          duration = [strduration intValue];
          minutes  = duration / 60;
          seconds  = duration % 60;

          // bgVideoLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
          if (minutes > 0 || seconds > 0)
          {
            [bgAssetMedia addObject:alPhoto];
          }
        } else {
          [bgAssetMedia addObject:alPhoto];
        }
      }
    }
     // NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)bgAssetMedia.count);
  }];
```

Then, we would switch to the foreground to update the UIViewController, which are these lines in the above snippet:

```
_assetPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[bgAssetMedia copy]];
```

The "copy" function was the black magic that allowed us to quickly marshal the memory from background to foreground without having to loop through array again.
Is there a similar method in Swift? Perhaps something like this:

```
_assetPhotos = NSMutableArray(array: bgAssetMedia.copy())
```

Is Swift thread safe now for passing memory pointers from background to foreground?  What's the new protocol?  Thank you-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  After running large queries on the Realm and CoreData database contexts.  I found it easy to just make a basic copy of the memory pointer and downcast it to match the class.

```
let mediaIdFG = mediaId.copy() as! String
```

Full example in context below:

```
static func createOrUpdate(dictionary:NSDictionary) -> Promise<Media> {
    // Query and update from any thread
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
      executeInBackground {
//        c("BG media \(dictionary)")
        let realm:RLMRealm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        let media = Media.createOrUpdateInRealm(realm, withJSONDictionary:dictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        // media.type = type
        c("BG media \(media)")
        let mediaId = media.localIdentifier
        do {
          try realm.commitWriteTransaction()
          executeInForeground({
            let mediaIdFG = mediaId.copy() as! String
            let newMedia = Media.findOneByLocalIdentifier(mediaIdFG)
            c("FG \(mediaIdFG) newMedia \(newMedia)")
            fulfill(newMedia)
          })
        } catch {
          reject( Constants.createError("Realm Something went wrong!") )
        }
      }
    } // return promise
  } // func createOrUpdate
```

Posting my own answer to let you know my findings.  I also found this helpful article about Swift's copy() aka objc's copyWithZone: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy